# Prove that a regular graph of degree 5 cannot be decomposed into subgraphs, each isomorphic to a path of length six

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that a regular graph of degree 5 cannot be decomposed into subgraphs, each isomorphic to a path of length six.

I think I should consider about the number of edges of 5-regular graphs but it seems hard for me to find the number of edges of 5-regular graphs. Can someone help me with this question? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you're combining lots of paths into a 5-regular graph, there's three things that can be happening at any given vertex:

- It is the middle of two paths, and the endpoint of a third path.
- It is the middle of one path, and the endpoint of three others.
- It is the endpoint of five paths.

So if your graph has $n$ vertices, the paths collectively have at most $2n$ middle vertices and at least $n$ endpoints, so the ratio $\frac{\text{number of middle vertices}}{\text{number of endpoints}}$ is at most $2$.

On the other hand, if the paths all have length $6$, then they all have $5$ middle vertices and $2$ endpoints, so the ratio $\frac{\text{number of middle vertices}}{\text{number of endpoints}}$ must be exactly $\frac52$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how do you know that "it is the middle of two paths, and the endpoint of a third path.......", these three statments are true? I am still confused about this.

Comment: The five edges out of a vertex have to be used up by paths. If the vertex is in the middle of some path, this uses up two of the edges: in total, $0$, $2$, or $4$ of the edges can be used up in this way. The remaining edges have to be used by a path that starts or ends at that vertex.